# Is $\log(X_1+X_2)$ a sufficient statistic for $\beta$?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

I have trouble finding the following sufficient statistics.
How do you do this?
$$X\sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$$
$$f(x;\alpha, \beta)=\frac{e^{-x/\beta}x^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}$$

**Question**:
Is $\log(X_1+X_2)$ a sufficient statistic for beta?

I am using the first way, conditional probability, but how to you plug it in and reduce?  But there's a log in it.

I understand there are two ways to find it:

1. Sufficiency principle:
   $$P(X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2,...X_n=x_n|T(X_1,...,X_n))$$
   does not depend on $\theta$.
2. Factorization theorem:
   $$P_\theta(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)=h(x_1, x_2,...x_n)g_\theta(T(x_1,x_2,...,x_n))$$
   where $h$ only depends on the observation vector $(x_1,...x_n)$ and not $\theta$.

Comment: This looks like a standard textbook problem. If this is for some subject, or otherwise for the purpose of your own study, would you mind adding the self-study tag, please?

Answer (score 2):

Sufficient for what? $\beta$ or $\alpha$?

If your sample size is 2, then you can quite easily show that $X_1+X_2$ is sufficient for $\beta$. Furthermore, any 1-1 function of a sufficient stats is itself a sufficient stats. therefore $\log(X_1+X_2)$ will be sufficient for $\beta$.

Comment: Yes, for $\beta$.  How do you show?  Way 1 or way 2?

Comment: Factorization. In case this is hw. DIY the rest mate.

Comment: If the answer helped you solve your problem, you might consider indicating that it was helpful.

Comment: $X_1+X_2\sim\Gamma(2\alpha, \beta)$  Where is the sufficient stat?  Like the sum of $X_i$ you usually see.

Comment: could you take a look below?

Comment: I take it this is hw? Several comments: 1. The beauty of the factorization theorem is that it provides an easy way to find sufficient stats. in other words, if you are using the factorization theorem, there is no need to go back to first principle (i.e. the conditional density). Using OP's terms, if you are using way 2, you don't need to use way 1. Secondly, distribution of $X_1+X_2$ if completely different to the bivariate distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$. The latter is simply the product of 2 univariate density, assuming $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Comment: I simply googled for some examples. I think the example in p.4 here will be helpful. http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st312-rich/suff2.pdf

Comment: it's for upcoming exam.  Is my answer below right or wrong?  Please comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I got, does it look correct?
$$f(X_1, X_2|T=x_1+x_2)$$
$$=\frac{e^{\frac{-x_1}{\beta}}x_1^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha} \frac{e^{\frac{-x_2}{\beta}}x_2^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}$$
$$=\frac{e^{\frac{-\sum{x_i}}{\beta}}(x_1x_2)^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)^2\beta^{2\alpha}}.$$

So, we have
$$h(x_1,x_2)=(x_1x_2)^{\alpha-1},$$ and $$g_\beta(T(x_1,x_2))=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)^2\theta^{2\alpha}}e^{-\sum{x_i}/\beta}.$$

By the factorization theorem, $X_1+X_2$ is a sufficient statistic for $\beta$.

Since $\log(\cdot)$ is a one to one function.  We say $\log(X_1+X_2)$ is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: The solution is incorrect as the first equation is the joint density of $(X_1,X_2)$ and not the conditional density.